# Reorder Windows Task Manager Performance Tab Items

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-manager

Is it possible to re-order the items listed in the Performance Tab in Windows Task Manager?

*Such as moving the "WiFi" item up to the top?*

[image]

Saw a similar post with no responses. [Ordering Task Manager performance tab](https://superuser.com/questions/1581507/ordering-task-manager-performance-tab)

Comment: I don't think there is a simple and easy way to this if even possible. I tried a little bit to find somethibg and I did some research but nothing. On Reddit r/Windows they say it's not possible so I guess it confirms it as of right now.